# Tab out function (sendkeys.TAB) is not working properly when the application is minimized or not in focus - Selenium Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My scenario is to enter a Unique ID into the DSID textbox and tabout. Then the application fetches the details regarding that ID from database and displays in the application. I am using Selenium Webdriver and Java to automate the above scenario. When i use (SendKeys.TAB) it's working and fetching details from database. But when the application is minimized or system is locked, application is not fetching details from database after tabout. I tried with Actions class and java script executor to send tab key but of no use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that the TAB is not being sent to the browser correctly when it is minimized or the system is locked. Do you have another option like clicking a different element on the page?

Comment: Yes jeffC, even if we click on other elements also it will fetch details from DB. I tried this option also and it worked only when the application is in focus but when the application is minimized or System is locked its not fetching details.

Comment: You'd have to post some of your code and relevant HTML but hopefully we can find a way to trigger the fetch without using TAB.

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js = null;

    if(GOC.driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor)
    {
     js = (JavascriptExecutor) GOC.driver;
    }

    WebElement Element = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.activeElement;"); 

    Element.sendKeys("112333535");

    Element.submit();

Above code works for me even if the application is minimized. But in my application Timer will be there which will start once we enter the ID in the DSID text box. That's getting resetted to 0 after performing the submit operation.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code you posted in the comment. It will make it easier to find and it can be properly formatted.